# Multi projects in a single git repo without mixed commits

Tags: git

I have a few git repos which are different components in the same project. The overhead of maintaining so many repositories and switching between them is too much for me.

But, what stops me from putting them in the same repo is that I do not want the commits to mix (I don't want one commit which contains changes in two or more directories).
This is important because part of the modules are forks of other projects and I might want to submit part of my work to the original repos.

The question is: Is there some tool which automatically splits a single commit into multiple commits (one per directory)?

(Even better: keeping the repos separate but having some mega-meta-repo which gives an illusion of a single repository and manages all the per-project commits under the hood ?)
Thanks

Comment: If you always commit in subdirectories, I don't see a massive overhead in having many repositories instead of one. I don't think you should try to have only one repository here if it's important to keep them ultimately separated.

Comment: Can you detail what the overhead is that you're trying to avoid?

Comment: Think having 10 repositories. This means, for one new "feature", I'll have to do 10 commits, do 10 times git status to make sure every thing is committed, 10 times push to origin, 10 times make sure that all changes are pushed to remote before.
even the simple task of checking that my local repo is aligned with my remote repo is time consuming. (10 git logs instead of 1) This is the overhead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been there too! Most times, submodules can be a PITA.

I recommend using a subtree (`git-subtree`), which is available since Git 1.7.11. Each subtree has its own independent history. Here's the [official documentation](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.txt).

Atlassian has a nice introduction to subtrees, [Alternatives To Git Submodule: Git Subtree](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/05/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree/).

Comment: Thank you. Sound a reasonable solution for what I need.